# Rewrite url in Ajax-driven website

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am biulding ajax driven website. So basically, I will have only one page "http://www.mysite.com/default.aspx"
I would like to get rid of this "default.aspx" and leave just "http://www.mysite.com".

How can I do this? Do I have to rewrite url? Or maybe it is possible to configure IIS to hide default site name and extension?

Comment: How about setting up the default document instead?

Comment: Do you mean set up default document in IIS like in this [link](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument) ? In this case if I add default.aspx to default document, site url should become just http://www.mysite.com instead of http://www.mysite.com/default.aspx ?

Comment: Yep! By default `default.aspx` should already be in there so if you hit `http://www.website.com` it should work, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, good point. I`ll give it a go :) Thank you.